# DB - When creating another entity to let the DB at the third normal form, is it necessary to make the new entity references the old one?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, normalization, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

Imagine I got this table:

```
a                     //primary key
b
c
```

Where `a -> bc` and `b -> c`. To let this at the third normal form, I must separate it in 2 tables:

```
a        //primary key
b
```

and

```
b        // primary key
c
```

My question is: Do I need to make `b` at the second table references `b` at the first table?

Answer (score 0):

you should.

A foreign key allows you to create relationship between the two tables, as the two tables are obviously related. It can also act as constraint such that when you attempt to add a record in `table2` with invalid value in column b, the insertion will be unsuccessful.

Comment: FKs get called "relationships" by misrepresentations of ERM & by some methods and tools. But they are not. They are facts. Tables can "be related" ie participate in relationships like "table [fkt] column list [fkcl] is a FK to table [ckt] column list [ckcl]". But each FK is an *instance* of that relationship. Ie "table bc column list {b} is a FK to table ab column list {b}", ie "table bc column list {b} subrow values are table ab column list {b} subrow values". An instance exists *if and only if* the (constant) constraint does. (Yes, declare to the DBMS.) Querying doen't need "related" tables.